# Mold growth around toilet

Tags: toilet, mold

We've got some mold growing around the base of our toilet (photos below). We're going to pull the toilet up to see what's going on, but wanted to get thoughts on what might be causing this, what to look for once we pull it up, and how to clean up once we do.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: If that's from a leaking wax ring, it might not be mold growing, but dirty water escaping and leaving deposits. Use your imagination and gloves.

Answer (score 1):

Condensation running down the outside of the toilet making the area damp.

Failed wax seal ring making it damp from the inside, and possibly not precisely "mold or mildew", or not **only** mold or mildew.

Regardless, you'll need a new wax ring since you are pulling the toilet, and you clean up with bleach solution to kill the mold (or other substances/lifeforms) (ventilation on, don't mix with ammonia, wear rubber gloves, etc...)